# Spring MockBean annotation cause " No qualifying bean of type MockitoPostProcessor is defined"

Tags: spring

I find if "old style", like `RunWith` annotation and `SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation, mixed with "new style" `MockBean` annotation, it looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestApplication.class)
@FixMethodOrder(value = MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SomeUnitTest {
    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private IWantTestThisService iWantTestThisService;

    @MockBean
    private DependencyInAboveService dependencyInAboveService;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // your test
    }
}
```

It will case exception:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor] is defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this exception, you should upgrade your code to

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@FixMethodOrder(value = MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SomeUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private IWantTestThisService iWantTestThisService;

    @MockBean
    private DependencyInAboveService dependencyInAboveService;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // your test
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing from `@Mock` to `@MockBean` did in fact solve my issue. I don't understand why the response is downvoted

Comment: Downvoting because you are answering your own question in the same minute. This feels like a monologue.

Comment: maybe he found the answer and just wanted to help the rest